# Reference to an image from different locations

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I am using Python Sphinx (via [ReadTheDocs](http://readthedocs.io)).

I have a repository which contains a few sub-modules, and I'm trying to create a unified documentation, but still keep the the *docs* assets in each module separately.

**My folder hierarchy is:**

```
MyProject
  docs
    index.rst
    module_1_link.rst
      _static
        <more irrelevant assets...>               
  module_1
    docs
      README.rst
      _static
        myimage.png
```

The `index.rst` file looks like this:

```
.. toctree::
    :caption: Module1
    module_1_link
```

The file `module_1_link.rst` just contains a link to the README file of module 1:

```
.. include:: ../module1/docs/README.rst
```

And the `README.rst` of module 1 references the image:

```
.. image:: _static/myimage.jpg
```

When I look at the README file of module 1 (inside GitHub) - `myimage.png` is shown perfectly.

But, when I run the documentation via Sphinx I get:

> WARNING: image file not readable: _static/myimage.jpg

I can't find a way to reference the same image from both the README file and the index file rendered by Sphinx and see it in both places.

Answer (score 8):

Change the reference to the image in `README.rst` to be relative to the documentation root.

```
.. image:: /module1/docs/_static/myimage.jpg
```

See also Sphinx documentation on [paths to images](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#images).

> When used within Sphinx, the file name given (here `gnu.png`) must either be relative to the source file, or absolute which means that they are relative to the top source directory. For example, the file `sketch/spam.rst` could refer to the image `images/spam.png` as `../images/spam.png` or `/images/spam.png`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Steve! So this definitly lets me see the image correctly in the module1 README.rst, but again, when the ReadTheDocs runs on the entire project I get "WARNING: image file not readable module1/docs/_static/myimage.jpg"

Comment: It sounds like part of your project was not installed by RTD. Got link to the build log?

Comment: Yes - https://readthedocs.org/projects/unicorn-project/builds/7726818/
Thanks you!

Comment: Try making your include directives root-relative as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Steve. I tried your last comment. still no luck but I'm trying more stuff